# sort contents of 4 different arrays into same order

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have 4 arrays:

```
self.packName.append(object["packName"] as! String)
self.packDescription.append(object["packDesctription"] as! String)
self.packTitle.append(object["packTitle"] as! String)
let image = object.value(forKey: "file") as? PFFile
self.packImage.append(image!)
```

At the moment they are created and everything lines up (i.e., the packName matches the packImage. however if i try and sort them

```
self.packName = self.packName.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
self.packDescription = self.packDescription.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
self.packTitle = self.packTitle.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
self.packImage = self.packImage.sorted(by: { $0.name < $1.name })
```

they come out all mishmatch because this is sorting each array alphabetically.

How can i sort all 4 the same?

Comment: Why maintain 4 parallel arrays? You should almost certainly be using an array of structs instead.

Comment: because I'm a n00b and i don't know what I'm doing, or even what to search for in this case :)  thanks for the tip i shall look into it.

Comment: @WanderingScouse https://www.raywenderlich.com/116714/swift-tutorial-introducing-structures

Answer (score 0):

This sorted it.  thanks for the tip guys

```
struct packStruct {
    var packName : String
    var packDescription : String
    var packTitle : String
    var packImage : PFFile
}

var packArray = [packStruct]()

var arrayName : String = ""
var arrayDescription : String = ""
var arrayTitle : String = ""
var arrayImage : PFFile

for object in packs {

    self.arrayName = object.object(forKey: "packName") as! String
    self.arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: "packDesctription") as! String
    self.arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: "packTitle") as! String
    self.arrayImage = object.object(forKey: "file") as! PFFile

    self.packArray.append(packStruct(packName: self.arrayName, packDescription: self.arrayDescription, packTitle: self.arrayTitle, packImage: self.arrayImage))

}
// returns the array with all the data
print(packArray)
```

and get the data from the array

```
self.packArray[indexPath.item].packDescription
```

and can sort:

```
self.packArray = self.packArray.sorted{ $0.packName < $1.packName }
```